# What is the usecase of Flux.repeat() without any parameter?

Tags: project-reactor

I was looking at the following code and was confused with what the repeat() operator is doing here.

```java
return inboundFlux
                .groupBy(record -> record.receiverOffset().topicPartition())
                .flatMap(partitionFlux -> partitionFlux
                        .concatMap(el -> Flux.just(el)
                                .doOnNext(receiverRecord -> {
                                    log.info("Starting to process {}", receiverRecord);
                                    messageProcessor.processMessage(receiverRecord);
                                    receiverRecord.receiverOffset().acknowledge();
                                    log.info("Message acknowledged");
                                })
                                .doOnError(e -> log.error("ERRRRRRROOORRRRRR"))
                                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).maxBackoff(Duration.ofSeconds(20)).transientErrors(true))
                                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                                    // code to handle retry exhaustion
                                })
                        ).repeat()
                )
                .subscribeOn(scheduler)
                .subscribe();
```

Comment: Is it just an infinite loop in a separate thread? `repeat() -- Repeatedly and indefinitely subscribe to the source upon completion of the previous subscription.`

Comment: @K.Nicholas what would be the behaviour on a hot flux vs cold flux? according to marble diafram it keeps on subscribing to same set of values but here it is not the case. The value of ```el``` is changing as long as retry is not triggered.

Comment: It is not subscribing to the same set of values. It re-subscribes on completion. If a hot flux never issues a completion I assume the repeat will never execute. Anyway, it looks like the `repeat()` is on the `partitionFlux`.